# React Native - App crashes while launching after implementing HMSCore

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services, huawei-mobile-services

I tried to run our app on Android Emulator but it crashes without showing any error message. It works fine on iOS and HarmonyOS devices. It was working before. I did not change anything but it started stopping app while launching. I get this error messages on Android Studio.

```
 2021-06-08 12:49:25.488 5944-5944/com.xxx E/HAInstanceManager: createInstance error
2021-06-08 12:49:25.590 5944-5980/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Failed to find HMS apk
2021-06-08 12:49:25.746 5944-5980/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Failed to find HMS apk
2021-06-08 12:49:25.842 5944-5980/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Failed to find HMS apk
2021-06-08 12:49:25.915 5944-5984/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Failed to find HMS apk
2021-06-08 12:49:25.933 5944-5984/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Failed to find HMS apk
2021-06-08 12:49:25.940 5944-5984/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Failed to find HMS apk
2021-06-08 12:49:25.946 5944-5984/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_SystemUtils: isSystemApp Exception: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.huawei.appmarket
2021-06-08 12:49:25.968 5944-5944/com.xxx E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found result: 0
2021-06-08 12:49:25.972 5944-5984/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HmsInstanceId: TokenTask failed, ErrorCode: 907135003
2021-06-08 12:49:25.974 5944-5984/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Failed to find HMS apk
2021-06-08 12:49:26.660 5944-5980/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Failed to find HMS apk
2021-06-08 12:49:26.661 5944-5980/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_AutoInit: Push init failed
2021-06-08 12:49:27.189 5944-5944/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Failed to find HMS apk
2021-06-08 12:49:27.314 5944-5944/com.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxx, PID: 5944
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at com.huawei.hms.rn.push.logger.HMSLogger.getInstance(HMSLogger.java:100)
        at com.huawei.hms.rn.push.remote.HmsPushMessageService.onTokenError(HmsPushMessageService.java:107)
        at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.a(HmsMessageService.java:34)
        at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.a(HmsMessageService.java:29)
        at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService.handleIntentMessage(HmsMessageService.java:7)
        at com.huawei.hms.push.HmsMessageService$a.handleMessage(HmsMessageService.java:7)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Is there anyone who faced this issue before? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: hi,Just to confirm,are you using Android's default emulator?

Comment: hi, yes I am using Android's default emulator Nexus 7 & Pixel 3

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta-data     
       android:name="push_kit_auto_init_enabled"  
       android:value="false" />
```

When we set auto init false in hms-push package it worked. There is another problem for ios devices. Package should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

> 2021-06-08 12:49:25.972 5944-5984/com.xxx E/HMSSDK_HmsInstanceId: TokenTask failed, ErrorCode: 907135003

This error code indicates that The HMS Core SDK fails to connect to HMS Core (APK). The possible cause is that the HMS Core process is stopped or crashed.

On a non-Huawei mobile phone, the HMS Core, as a third-party application, may be killed by the system process. As a result, the HMS Core may cannot be used.

In addition, the HMS Core APK is also required on non-Huawei phones.The application performs a boot upgrade. If the system prompts you to upgrade the HMS Core APK, perform operations as prompted.

Comment: I have huawei test device (P40 Lite). The apk works fine on it. But the problem is that apk is not working on any other Android devices. Do I still need to use Cloud Debugging ? Also I submitted integration check and it passed

Comment: hi Emre D,can you check your other Android devices 's App Store HMS Core version?You can search HMS Core in your App Store to see the current  HMS Core version.

Comment: I do not think it is about HMS Core version. Why would Google users download HMS Core? I uninstall hms-push package and it worked. Then I installed npm i @hmscore/react-native-hms-push and it crashed :) I guess we found the problem :)

Comment: hi Emre D,i just updated my answer,pls kindly refer.

Comment: @EmreD. If I understand correctly , so things are different in React Native, So I prefer to use [`HmsPushMessaging.setAutoInitEnabled`](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References-V1/hmsmessage-0000001050155856-V1#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050155856__section2041314303310) method for React Native.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour I use HmsPushMessaging.turnOnPush it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You might want to disable [Huawei Push Kit Automatic Initialization](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/performautoinitial-0000001050157799-V1) by using [`HmsPushMessaging.setAutoInitEnabled`](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References-V1/hmsmessage-0000001050155856-V1#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050155856__section2041314303310) method.

```
import { HmsPushMessaging } from "@hmscore/react-native-hms-push";

HmsPushMessaging.setAutoInitEnabled(false)
  .then((result) => {
    this.log("setAutoInitEnabled", result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    alert("[setAutoInitEnabled] Error/Exception: " + JSON.stringify(err));
  });
```